# Input validation with the scala type system

Tags: scala, validation, types, implicit-conversion

Having played a bit with Scala now, I question myself how you should do input validation in Scala.

This is what I have seen many times:

```
def doSomethingWithPositiveIntegers(i: Int) = {
    require(i>0)
    //do something
}
```

to bring matters to a head, it feels like doing this in Java:

```
void doSomething(Object o) {
    if (!o instanceof Integer)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

There, you first accept more than you are willing to accept, and then introduce some "guard" that only lets the "good ones" in. To be exact, you'd need these guards in every function that does something with positive integers, and in case you'd like for example to include zero later on, you'd need to change every function. Of course you can shift it to another function, but nevertheless you'd always need to rember to call the correct function, and it might not survive type refactorings etc. Does not sound that I'd like to have that. I was thinking about pushing this validation code to the data type itself, like this:

```
import scala.util.Try

object MyStuff {
    implicit class PositiveInt(val value: Int) {
        require(value>0)
    }
    implicit def positiveInt2Int(positiveInt: PositiveInt): Int = positiveInt.value
}

import MyStuff._

val i: MyStuff.PositiveInt = 5
val j: Int = i+5
println(i)  //Main$$anon$1$MyStuff$PositiveInt@3a16cef5
println(j)  //10
val sum = i + i
println(sum)    //10

def addOne(i: MyStuff.PositiveInt) = i + 1

println(Try(addOne(-5)))    //Failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed)
println(Try(addOne(5)))     //Success(6)
```

Then I have a type `PositiveInt` that can only contain positive integers, and I can use it (almost) everywhere like an `Int`. Now, my API defines what I am willing to take - this is what I'd like to have! The function itself has nothing to validate, because it knows it can only get valid positive integers - they cannot be constructed without validation. You'd have to run your validation only once - upon creation of the type! Think of other cases, where validation might be more expensive (validate an email address or URL, or that a number is a prime).

Advantages:

1. Your API tells you directly what kind of objects you accept (no more `do(String, String, String)` what could be `do(User, Email, Password)`)
2. Your objects get validated "automatically"
3. The compiler can help you reduce the risk of bugs. Some things that you'd before see on run time can be seen on compile time. Example:

   ```
   def makeNegative(i: PositiveInt): NegativeInt = -i
   addOne(makeNegative(1)) //will create a compile-time error!
   ```

However, there are some drawbacks:

1. Unfortunately, you break many functions that work due to implicit conversions. E.g., this will not work:

   ```
   val i: PositiveInteger = 5
   val range = i to 10        //error: value to is not a member of this.MyStuff.PositiveInt
   val range = i.value to 10  //will work
   ```

   It could be solved if you could extend `Int` and just add the `require`, because then all `PositiveInt` are `Int`s (what really is the case!), but `Int` is final :). You could add implicit conversions for all the cases you need, but that would be pretty verbose.
2. More objects are created. Maybe one can lower that burden with value classes (can anybody show me how?).

These are my questions:

1. Am I missing something? I have not seen anybody do this before, and I wonder why. Maybe there are good reasons for not doing this.
2. Is there a better way to integrate validation into my types?
3. How can I avoid the problems with the need of duplicate implicits (drawback #1)? Maybe some kind of macro that looks at other implicits in scope and adds implicits at compile time for me (Example: implicit conversion from `PositiveInt` to `RichInt`)?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a class with a private constructor visible to a companion object with a factory method e.g.

```
class PositiveInt private[PositiveInt](val i: Int)

object PositiveInt {
    def apply(i: Int): Option[PositiveInt] = if(i > 0) Some(new PositiveInt(i)) else None
}
```

clients cannot create instances of `PositiveInt` directly so they have to go through the `apply` method which does the validation and only returns valid instances if the input value is valid.

Comment: Yes, but - what I'd like to achieve is that users do not need to be aware that there is validation in place. In this case, I need to explicitly instantiate the `PositiveInt` instances - I can't simply call functions requiring a `PositiveInt` with (positive) `Int` instances. But this is what I'd like to do...

Comment: an `apply` method returning an `Option` is unintuitive, if anything you want an `unapply` or `fromInt` or something like that.